Connecting docker image(Spring boot app) to MySQL Database
I have an api that i have built an image out of. I am trying to run it using docker compose with the services (database included) I keep getting Connection failure error, I have tried the other solutions I found on the internet to it but I was not able to solve it. At first the app was not connecting to the Db (running in a container) whether it was also running locally(the app) or running inside the container, but after changing the URL to match, I have been able to get the app to work. it now connects to the DB(running on a container) if I run the API locally but when I use docker compose to run the app(running inside a conatiner and the db inside a container), it does not connect to the database.
This is my docker compose file
version: "2.4"
services:
  trivia-quiz:
    image: omotoso/trivia-quiz-api
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: PROD
    depends_on:
      - mysql

  mysql:
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - "3000:3306" 
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db
      MYSQL_USER: my_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
  
volumes:
  mysql-data:

This the app.yaml fle fo the spring boot app
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    password: password
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3000/db
    username: my_user
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: false`

I am expecting the app to connect to the db successfully but I am getting this error
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar!/:8.3.0]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar!/:8.3.0]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:815) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar!/:8.3.0]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:438) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar!/:8.3.0]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar!/:8.3.0]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:189) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar!/:8.3.0]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:100) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]


@nbk thank you for the edit, I made a mistake while trying to post

I have added network to the docker compose file and also I am using mysql:3306 to connect to the database and not localhost:3000. Still the same error

Use jdbc:mysql://mysql:3000/db since you are exposing port 3000 mysql docker container.

So exposing that did not work, what worked for me was defining the env variable of the url inside the compose file. since the application is running in a container and connecting to the db also running in the container, I do not even need to d port binding
